# ssh2 connection to linux over php

Tags: php, linux, ssh, gnu-screen

i try to update my minecraft whitelist over php to my linux server.
The connection works but i dont know why he didnt send my command to add the user to the whitelist.

Here my code:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mc=$_POST['mc'];
if($ssh = ssh2_connect('127.0.0.1', 22)) {
if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', 'password')) {
    $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'screen -R '.$mc.' && '.'whitelist add '.$name.' && whitelist reload');
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $data = '';
    while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
        $data .= $buffer;
    }
    fclose($stream);
    echo $data;
}
}
```

Comment: Sending unfiltered POST data to the shell is never going to end well.

Comment: You want to execute command `whitelist add xxx && whitelist reload` inside screen?

Comment: yes first i want to open the screen with screen -R mctechnic than i wand to add userxyz to whitelist

oh 2answers didnt see xD first time @stackoverflow

i tried to do it without POST
screen -R mctechnic didnt work either

Answer (score 1):

You are joining commands with `&&` and all of them will be executed one after another in your current shell, not inside screen. `screen` can execute commands inside selected session, but with it's own syntax. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049252/how-to-create-a-screen-executing-given-command), for example, or [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). In your case, command must look like this:

```sh
screen -S session_name -X stuff $'whitelist add user_name && whitelist reload\n'
```

Note `\n` symbol at the end of string. It is required in order to execute command because `screen` will not really execute it, `screen` will "send the specified command to a running screen session" as manual says. Consider that screen will type command instead of you. And when you typing command, you must press Enter/Return to execute it.

In PHP you can execute command this way:

```php
$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, "screen -S $mc -X stuff \$'whitelist add $name && whitelist reload\\n'");
```