# Running "screen -S" using SSH.net C# library

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, ssh.net

I want to use SSH.net library (https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET
)  to execute commands on a linux box over SSH.

Here is a sample code:

```
        SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("13.93.231.87", 22, "user", "pass");
        cSSH.Connect();

        var cmd = "screen -S screenName";
        SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand(cmd);
```

I see x.Result, it contains following:

```
        x.Result = "Must be connected to a terminal.\r\n"
```

What does it mean? Is it not possible to use "screen" commands via Ssh.NET? Or is there another way to achieve it?

What i want to achieve is having a C# console application which executes commands on a linux box under a screen. And then I should be able to connect the same screen again and execute commands and detach screen. And continue doing that.

Comment: Refer - http://serverfault.com/questions/21806/how-can-i-launch-a-screen-session-with-a-command-over-ssh-on-a-remote-server-fro

Comment: You aren't starting anything, so screen exits because it has nothing to keep open.  Try something like

var cmd = "screen -S screenName /bin/sh";

So you spawn a shell "inside" your new screen process.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049314/2003763