# Process killed after closing terminal SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, hosting, vps

I'm trying to clear facebook cache on my server every 2 seconds so i logged in the SSH and i run this command

```
while true; do sleep 2; curl -F id="http://twd.ma" -F scrape=true -F access_token='token' -F appID=appID https://graph.facebook.com; done &
```

And every thing worked fine and the cache started to be cleaned every 2 seconds. However, when i close the Terminal SSH the cache stop being cleaned and i think the process is killed, what should i do please?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command will stop executing because when you log out, the shell is lost. The '&' means that the script runs in background "as long as the shell is active"

You can do the following:
Write your script into a file, i.e. clearcache.sh and omit the '&'

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
sleep 2
curl -F id="http://twd.ma" -F scrape=true -F access_token='token' -F appID=appID https://graph.facebook.com
done
```

Write the path to your script into /etc/rc.local

```
/path/to/clearcache.sh > /dev/null 2&>1 &
```

The ' >/dev/null 2&>1 means that all output that your script produces will be deleted.

Comment: and is there a better way without a script?

Comment: you could use a screen session for that
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049252/how-to-create-a-screen-executing-given-command

Answer (score 1):

If `screen` is available to you then you can start a screen session by running `screen`, run your commands, then press `ctrl-a ctrl-d` to detach the session.

When you log in later you can issue `screen -r` to reconnect to the detached session.