# Automate loading of multiple unix screens with commands

Tags: python, unix, gnu-screen

I need to run 20 experiments in parallel. For each, I am loading a new unix `screen`, then within that loading an anaconda environment, and then running a python script with an argument for that experiment.

The workflow looks like:

```
> screen -S exp01
> source activate myenv
(myenv) > python process_experiment 01
> screen -S exp02
> source activate myenv
(myenv) > python process_experiment 02
```

Is there a way to write a script to automate it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049252/how-to-create-a-screen-executing-given-command), you can send keystrokes to a `screen` session like so:

> ```
> screen -dmS new_screen sh
> screen -S new_screen -X stuff "cd /dir
> "
> screen -S new_screen -X stuff "java -version
> "
> ```

You could write a small shell script (let's call it `run-exp.sh`) to set your experiment running:

```
#!/bin/sh
source activate myenv
python process_experiment $1
```

And then use a loop to start screen sessions running that script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq -w 1 20); do
    screen -dmS exp$i
    screen -S exp$i -X stuff "./run-exp.sh $i
"
    # (The new line is necessary, not a mistake.)
done
```

Comment: I just realized an error in my description: the experiment number needs to be 2 digits, so 1 needs to be 01

Comment: Oops, this does '01' instead of 1, right? In any case, I'm not seeing anything in any screen

Comment: Yes, the `-w` flag makes `seq` pad the lower numbers with zeros. Hmm. Not totally sure how to debug; are the screen sessions being created correctly?

Comment: Yes, there are 20 screen sessions that I see listed. But nothing is happening in them.

Comment: So another way of executing a command within the session is to pass it as an argument to the shell when you create the shell. So, in this case, inside the `for` loop try just `screen -dmS exp$i bash -c "./run-exp.sh $i"`.

Comment: Correction: "…when you create the _session_."

Comment: hmmm, still not doing anything