# How to execute commands in new tabs?

Tags: macos, shell, scripting

I want to start two different databases but want to keep each process running in a separate tab in a terminal. How do I do this within a shell script? I currently have the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash
mysqld &
redis-server
```

Each database needs its own tab. This is on OSX.

Comment: tabs? You want two *interactive* shell windows to input/output some info to db? Then, why not to run them in separate shells? For monitoring output, you could also redirect your output to *log files*. [Also you can start *screen*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1781533/1566267): `screen -S 'itismysqld' -d -m mysqld`, then, later attach: `screen -r itismysqld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "mysqld" in selected tab of the front window'
```

(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177891/1566267)

The similar command is for `redis-server`.