# Bash; Not running command in screen created

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm new to all of this so I probably made a big rookie mistake. I want to start a screen, which was successful, and then run command, which is not working. When I terminate the screen the command runs, but it needs to be ran on that specific screen. Thank you all in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

cd ~/Directory/

screen -S "Screen_Name"; java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543737/how-do-you-start-unix-screen-command-with-a-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate commands, separated by `;`. The second command, as you've observed, doesn't run until the first one exits. What you want is to pass the `java` command and its arguments as arguments to `screen`.

```
screen -S "Screen_Name" java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
```

This will run the `java` command in the `screen` session's initial window. When the `java` command exits, the `screen` session will terminate as well.